How to use "as a something" when the something is an object in the sentence
For example, if I am a man talking to a woman. And I want to say something like this..

As a woman, I request you to be kind to our children

However, this seems grammatically wrong since I am not a woman, as "As a woman" is coming before "I request"
This seems grammatically correct, but weird:

As a woman, you're requested to be kind and gentle

How can I use "As a woman" here while keeping the sentene in natural, active voice?

"I request you, as a woman..."

Your first version As a woman, I request you to be kind to our children is syntactically invalid, because the "subject" of the first three words must be the first noun that follows.

There's often ambiguity with "as" because it doesn't have an explicit reference; you could use "because you are a woman..." Or (this is a rule in most style guides) you could avoid generalizing about people on the basis of their gender.

Those kinds of ideas are rather sexist in the West. And we don't usually go around saying "request" to a spouse. We ask a spouse to do something. If either parent is screaming at the other, the other might say: I'm asking you to keep your voice down.

Or simply "Please keep your voice down."

The first example has a misplaced-modifier problem.  We could instead say
I ask you as a parent to be kind to our children.
I've shifted the modifier, changed the noun to parent to remove the sexism, and used ask instead of request.
Edit
We can also go without the modifier, which feels less confrontational:
I ask you to be kind to our children.
In a different context, we could say
I ask (or 'request')
you (as a supervisor) to be kind to your staff.
